# TastyPie - Upload image file on worker and simply set the path

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a worker that takes in a video and generates a thumbnail of that video. The worker then uploads the thumbnail to S3.

What I want to do is upon completion hit a TastyPie resource and save the path that the image was uploaded to. But I'm having trouble because TastyPie is expecting a File to be sent and I'm sending just the path.

Is there a way to fake upload this file?

`class Video(models.Model):
  thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)`

`class VideoResource(NamespacedModelResource):
    thumbnail = fields.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    def hydrate_thumbnail(self, bundle):
        # The following is obviously wrong.
        # bundle.data['thumbnail'] is set to the path that the image is already stored
        from django.core.files import File
        return File(bundle.data['thumbnail'])`

Comment: If you are just going to save the path every time, then it should be modelled that way. You might have to use CharField to store than path instead of the ImageField.